# How come this simple lexical specification fails?

Tags: compilation, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

I have a simple lexical specification in `a.flex`

```
%%
username    printf("%s",getlogin());
```

Running *flex a.flex* gives me

```
a.flex:2: EOF encountered inside an action
```

Any idea?

Comment: @brian: I think you should make that an answer. Even if it isn't the cause of this problem, the symptoms are 100% consistent and the answer may help someone else who stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs commonly with flex as it is picky about recognising lines. You will have missed the end-of-line symbol before the end-of-file.

Using your text editor to append a line to the end of file will resolve your error.

This can occur on both Windows and unix/linux/Mac versions of the flex tool.